# How to replace the pattern of passing callbacks with promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using Bluebird as a promise library and I have the following callback pattern that I would like to use promises for.

```
var func = function(err, data) {
    if(err) { // do this with err }
    else { // do this with data }
}
```

Desired calling pattern:

```
func.resolve(data);
func.reject(err);
```

How would I modify the original function definition to support the desired calling pattern?